# Class , Method , Instance creation and Main equivalent to Java in Python

Tags: java, python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am trying to implement a sample python program with class , some method and instance creation (object creation) with main method . But I am new to python I tried with lot of example but I am not getting the exact flow of the above in python . Below is the java code i need the equivalent in python .

```
Class hello {            //Class name

    void display () {          // user defined method    
        System.out.println("Hello");    
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) { //main method    
        hello obj=new hello();  //instance creation (object creation)
        obj.display();  // invoking methods 
    }
}
```

Output

```
Hello
```

I need the above code in python please help me out in this

The python what I tried with the same

```
import sys

class MyApplication():

    def get_name():
        print 'hi'

def main():
    app=MyApplication()
    print('Hi ' + app.get_name())

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

But this above python code is not working and not giving any error and output .I am getting blank console

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In python, intendation is very important. If you intend some code segment, it means that code segment is part of a block.

See following snippet from your code

```
def main():
    app=MyApplication()
    print('Hi ' + app.get_name())

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

You should correct indentation of this code segment. It should be,

```
def main():
    app = MyApplication()
    print('Hi ' + app.get_name())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

> '__main__' is the name of the scope in which top-level code executes.
>   A module’s __name__ is set equal to '__main__' when read from standard
>   input, a script, or from an interactive prompt.
>
> A module can discover whether or not it is running in the main scope
>   by checking its own __name__, which allows a common idiom for
>   conditionally executing code in a module when it is run as a script or
>   with python -m but not when it is imported:
>   A module can discover whether or not it is running in the main scope
>   by checking its own __name__, which allows a common idiom for
>   conditionally executing code in a module when it is run as a script or
>   with python -m but not when it is imported: - [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your replay after doing the modification it is working and also added "self" inside my method `get_name(self)` as args it is working now

Code Below

```
import sys

class MyApplication():

    def get_name(self):
        print   'hi'


def main():
    app=MyApplication()
    app.get_name()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```